# Converting Excel XML-Spreadsheet into xlsx

Tags: c#, xml, excel, openxml, spreadsheetml

i have got a XML-Excel file (SpreadsheetML format):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-    microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
 <Company>My Company</Company>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <Styles>
 <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
 <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
 <Borders/>
 <Font/>
 <Interior/>
 <NumberFormat/>
 <Protection/>
 </Style>
 <Style ss:ID="stTxt">
<Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8"/>
<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left"/>
<NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
 </Style>
<Style ss:ID="stTopHeadline">
<Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" />
<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left"/>
<NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/>
 </Style>
...
```

Now i need to convert those files into XLSX-Files with C#. Is there a way with Open Xml or other libraries to convert it into Excel 2010 XLSX format?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy example how to convert it with Python and an installed Excel.
Prerequisite: Microsoft Excel must be installed on the computer!

```
import os
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def convert_xls_to_xlsx(oldName:str, newName:str):
    oldName = os.path.abspath(oldName)
    newName = os.path.abspath(newName)
    xlApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(oldName)
    wb.SaveAs(newName,51)
    wb.Close(True)
```

Comment: import module pywin32

Answer (score 0):

What you got is called the Flat OPC format. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/09/29/transforming-flat-opc-format-to-open-xml-documents/) is an article about converting it to the regular Open XML format.

Comment: In Flat OPC you got tags like this:  `<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">`  SpreadsheetML is different: [link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpreadsheetML)

Comment: @Saftpresse99 The SpreadsheetML is contained inside the package.

Comment: The sample code in the article cannot convert SpreadsheetML into a package. Because namespaces and attributes are different.